# How to group Angular declarations and provider

Tags: angular

I been googling around trying to find a way to group decorations and provider, but haven't found a solutions. Although i did tried this but is not working!

The problem that i am facing is that i have over 20 decorators components and providers and app.module.ts is becoming too long so i want a way to group them into features.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './routing/app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './view/header/menu/menu.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './view/footer/footer/footer.component';
import body from './view/body/body.features';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ...body.components
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**body.features.ts**

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';
import { TransactionComponent } from './transaction/transaction.component';

const components = [
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    TransactionComponent
]

export default {
    components
}
```

As you can see that i am trying to inject an body component array into declarations, when launch angular was not able to load them properly.

Comment: make sure that the paths are correct in body.features.ts and one component is not declared in two files. I just did this in my project and it works fine.

Comment: My linter is saying all the path is correct and it have no build error. hmm

Comment: if there are no build errors, you must be able to view the components in the browser. Please attach the error screenshot, if any.

Comment: Ohh dammit... you are right it does work. I was missing AppComponent ! in my declarations